# My battery is not charging after power outage

Tags: 11.10, battery

I just emerged from 6 days power outage and now my MSI U100 is not charging the battery. Clicking on the battery indicator says 0% in spite of having been plugged in for 30+ minutes. If I unplug it, the machine turns off.

If I run: `cat /proc/acpi/battery/BAT1/state`

I get back...

```
present:                 yes
capacity state:          ok
charging state:          charged
present rate:            0 mA
remaining capacity:      0 mAh
present voltage:         8492 mV
```

Perhaps I fried the charging circuit when the power came back on...

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a windows install or live CD to test with? This sounds like a hardware issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for sure a hardware problem, to test simply turn your laptop off, plug in power supply, wait 30 mins, remove power supply, try to turn it on. If it does not then it can be the charge circuit of the battery or the battery itself (I had a Dell that the battery refused to charge even tough the diagnostics say it was ok to charge).

Comment: I agree that this is hardware... I'm reasonably sure that I burned out my charger circuit.

Comment: If you need any help looking for spare parts let me know ;) gl with it!